# IntelliJ doesn't recognize Angular Material HTML tags

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am starting over a very simple project with Angular 5 and Angular Material.

IntelliJ won't recognize Angular Material HTML tags:
[image: IntelliJ won't recognize Angular Material HTML tags]

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {CoreModule} from "@app/core";
import {SharedModule} from "@app/shared";
```

This is `AppModule` which imports `SharedModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Which imports and exports Angular Material related modules:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform- browser/animations";
import {MatToolbarModule} from "@angular/material";
import {NgReduxModule} from "@angular-redux/store";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    NgReduxModule,
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    NgReduxModule,
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: the error comes from [Angular language service](https://angular.io/guide/language-service), not from Intellij IDEA itself... Does your code work? Did you try re-starting the service using **Restart TypeScript Service** button in Typescript toolwindow?

Comment: It works, I will try that

Comment: Still dont work

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes dev dependencies are not properly installed.

try `npm i --only=dev`